# Config multiple IPs for apache server

Tags: networking, server, ip

We have a Rootserver and the Support guy told us "you have 5 IPs and I configured one"

Now I edited the file `/etc/network/interfaces` to following:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
 auto p2p1
 iface p2p1 inet static
    address 94.xxx.xxx.102
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 94.xxx.xxx.0
    broadcast 94.xxx.xxx.255
    gateway 94.xxx.xxx.1
    # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
    dns-search hoster.com

iface p2p1:1 inet static
    adress 94.xxx.xx.116
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 94.xxx.xxx.0
    broadcast 94.xxx.xx.255
    gateway 94.xxx.xxx.1
    #dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
    dns-search hoster.com

iface p2p1:2 inet static
    adress xxx.xxx.xxx.117
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 94.xxx.xxx.0
    broadcast 94.xxx.xxx.0
    gateway 94.xxx.xxx.1
    #dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
    dns-search hoster.com

iface p2p1:3 inet static
    adress 94.xxx.xxx.118
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 94.xxx.xxx.0
    broadcast 94.xxx.xxx.0
    gateway 94.xxx.xxx.1
    #dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
    dns-search hoster.com

 iface p2p1:4 inet static
    adress 94.xxx.xxx.119
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 94.xxx.xxx.0
    broadcast 94.xxx.xxx.0
    gateway 94.xxx.xxx.1
#dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
    dns-search hoster.com
```

Did I miss something? After Reboot it still does not work. It is my first time configuring multiple IPs.

Comment: You should not need the :1,:2,:3,:4 check out this simple config file for multiple IPs on the same interface. https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/linux-static-ip-configuration#debian--ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stanzas for IP aliases should have minimal data and an `auto` statement for each. I prefer to use the last octet as the alias number.  This is the configuration I would use.

```
auto p2p1:116
iface p2p1:116 inet static
   address xxx.xxx.xxx.116
   netmask 255.255.255.0

auto p2p1:117
iface p2p1:117 inet static
   address xxx.xxx.xxx.117
   netmask 255.255.255.0

auto p2p1:118
iface p2p1:118 inet static
   address xxx.xxx.xxx.118
   netmask 255.255.255.0

auto p2p1:119
iface p2p1:119 inet static
   address xxx.xxx.xxx.119
   netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Alternatively, if you have the `ip` command installed you can add the addresses in the `p2p1` stanza withe addition of lines like this:

```
up ip addr add xxx.xxx.xxx.116/24 dev p2p1 || true
up ip addr add xxx.xxx.xxx.117/24 dev p2p1 || true
up ip addr add xxx.xxx.xxx.118/24 dev p2p1 || true
up ip addr add xxx.xxx.xxx.119/24 dev p2p1 || true
```

Details can be found in the output of `man interfaces`.